# Does the Star Wars universe have sex droids?

Tags: star-wars, droids

From the list on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Droid/Legends#Droid_types), droids in the *Star Wars* universe categorized by function include Assassin droids, Interrogation droids, Astromech droids, battle droids, medical droids, etc. (the list goes on).

So, are there any droids that are primarily designed for pleasure, for example, sex droids?

Looking for answers across all media.

I haven't read any comics of the SW universe, but I do welcome answers from the comics as well.

Comment: Kind of have to, if there are [only two women in the whole galaxy](https://9gag.com/gag/516544/the-only-other-chick-in-the-galaxy-family-guy)

Comment: Does it have to be a sex bot in particular, or would a more PG-13 form of entertainment suffice? (e.g. a massage droid or a lounge singer droid) Also, are you looking just for purpose-built models or does a modification count?

Comment: @Yasskier and both were apparently Carrie Fisher :p :p

Comment: And if not, _why not?!?_

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sex_droid

Comment: @Cadence: personally, I'll take whatever you've got.

Comment: @Cadence by looking at their relationship in *Solo*, Lando may have used L3-37 as a sex bot. but I'm thinking there may be droids made spcifcially as sexbots

Comment: @PaulD.Waite you've got a point there. *if not, why not!!!* :p

Comment: IIRC it was implied that Black Sun Boss Prince Xizor used his HRD Guri in that way - and at the very least he could have. Being fully functional in every way is kind of the point of a Human Replicant Droid. So if you have the monetary equivalent of 60 X-Wings lying around (Guri cost a mere 9 million credits, an X-Wing you get for 150k). Later model HRDs were programmed to even be unaware of being droids, so if they were anatomically incorrect they would notice this about themselves... unless programmed to ignore it...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Legends, yes. Sex droids are mentioned in the novel *Planet of Twilight* by Barbara Hambly as part of *The Callista Trilogy*.

> Yarbolk sniffed and jabbed one short finger at the protocol droid for emphasis. “Loronar might not do it themselves, but they’d get Getelles to do it. Who do you think put those Gopso’o on me, back on Drovis? My sources at Getelles’s court tell me Loronar is pretty much backing Getelles’s whole household. **The local CEO, Dymurra, lives there like a king: sex droids, vibrobaths, plug-ins,** glitterstim, four different chefs, self-conforming slippers, independently controlled environments in every room of his mansion, you name it. Some stuff that isn’t legal anywhere. He couldn’t get it without Getelles’s okay. That all adds up to …”

Answer (score 9):

In the "honorable mentions" category, there's [C8-42-GE3](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/C8-42-GE3) from *Knights of the Old Republic*, a protocol droid belonging to one Elise Montagne. When her husband died, Elise became rather unhealthily fixated on the droid as a replacement, treating it like him in what is implied to be intimate ways (although, perhaps understandably, nobody in Revan's party is exactly eager to dig for details). Whether C8 was "functional" - and if so, *how* - is not elaborated on.